# Python: Outputting the results of an iterative procedure as a list

Tags: python

```
def sieve(num):
    notprime = []
    for i in range(2, num+1):                   
        if i not in notprime:                        
            for k in range(i*i, num+1, i):
                notprime.append(k)
            print i

def unitTest():                                  
    sieve(1000)
```

This the program I have written to find prime numbers. It works perfectly, but I want it to output a list of the numbers. ex: [2, 3, 5, 7......]. I can't, for the life of me, get this to happen and would hope someone out there would be able to help me with this.

Comment: For your curiosity more than anything else: http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~dstromberg/primes/

Answer (score 2):

Just declare a new list `primes`, append `i` and, return or print the list at the end of your `sieve` method:

```
def sieve(num):
    notprime = []
    primes = []
    for i in range(2, num + 1):
        if i not in notprime:
            for k in range(i * i, num + 1, i):
                notprime.append(k)
            primes.append(i)
    print primes

def unitTest():                                  
    sieve(1000)
```

**Output:**

```
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17,...]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also turn your function into a generator:

```
def sieve(num):
    notprime = []
    for i in range(2, num+1):                   
        if i not in notprime:                        
            for k in range(i*i, num+1, i):
                notprime.append(k)
            yield i

def unitTest():                                  
    list(sieve(1000))
```

This would save some memory for future use (even though the `notprime` list is way bigger).

Answer (score 0):

You need to first create the list and append each prime number to that list; exactly like you did with the `notprime` list.  After you've completely iterated through your loop, you can then print the full list:

```
def sieve(num):
    notprime = []
    prime = []
    for i in range(2, num+1):                   
        if i not in notprime:                        
            for k in range(i*i, num+1, i):
                notprime.append(k)
            prime.append(i)
    print prime
```

Answer (score 0):

One-liner for those interested.

```
def sieve(num):         
    return sorted(set([aa for aa in range(2, num+1)]) - set([z for i in range(2, num+1) for z in list(set(range(2, num+1)) & set([k for k in range(i*i, num+1, i)]))]))
```